# Как добавить JS функции?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть интересный скрипт, http://codepen.io/cl0udc0ntr0l/pen/xhBtF Так вот, как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку Onn вызывалась функция которая дает нам например `alert('Вы только что включили это!');` а когда нажимаем на `off alert('Вы только что выключили это!');` Как это сделать? Пробовал добавить onclick но что не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // The flicker is a codepen thing
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle-on');
  if($(this).hasClass('toggle-on'))
    {
      alert('ON');
    }else{
        alert('OFF');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // The flicker is a codepen thing
    $(this).toggleClass('toggle-on');

    if ($(this).is('.toggle-on')) {
      alert('Вы только что включили это!');
    } else {
      alert('Вы только что выключили это!');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
  html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #141219;
  }
  #switch {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 75px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  .toggle {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #444249;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: border-color .6s ease-out;
    transition: border-color .6s ease-out;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .toggle.toggle-on {
    border-color: rgba(137, 194, 217, .4);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s .15s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s .15s ease-out;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    width: 28px;
    bottom: 4px;
    right: 39px;
    background-color: #444249;
    border-radius: 19px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s, width .1s, top .1s, bottom .1s;
    transition: all .3s .1s, width .1s, top .1s, bottom .1s;
  }
  .toggle-on .toggle-button {
    top: 3px;
    width: 65px;
    bottom: 3px;
    right: 3px;
    border-radius: 23px;
    background-color: #89c2da;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px #4b7a8d;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s .1s, right .1s;
    transition: all .2s .1s, right .1s;
  }
  .toggle-text-on {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    /* Chrome/Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none;
    /* IE10+ */
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  .toggle-on .toggle-text-on {
    color: #3b6a7d;
    -webkit-transition: color .3s .15s;
    transition: color .3s .15s;
  }
  .toggle-text-off {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 6px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    /* Chrome/Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none;
    /* IE10+ */
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #444249;
  }
  .toggle-on .toggle-text-off {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  /* used for streak effect */
  .glow-comp {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: rgba(75, 122, 141, .1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(75, 122, 141, .2);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 4.5s 1s;
    transition: opacity 4.5s 1s;
  }
  .toggle-on .glow-comp {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toggle' id='switch'>
  <div class='toggle-text-off'>OFF</div>
  <div class='glow-comp'></div>
  <div class='toggle-button'></div>
  <div class='toggle-text-on'>ON</div>
```